# Getting geolocation to work on ZTE Open C

Tags: mobile, geolocation, firefox-os

it seems I can't get geolocation to work in FFOS 1.3.0. The default shipped "Here Maps" does Work but my App does not even ask for the Permission.
The Code does work on my Notebook, here I'm asked for the Location which is then provieded. I Guess it's the fault of the manifest file though I don't know what exactly is the Problem.

```
    {
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "Example",
  "description": "Example",
  "launch_path": "/index.html",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/icon_016.png",
    "32": "/images/icon_032.png",
    "48": "/images/icon_048.png",
    "128": "/images/icon_128.png"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "Example",
    "url": "http://www.example.de"
  },
  "default_locale": "de",
  "type": "privileged",
  "permissions": {
    "geolocation": {
      "description": "Used to locate me"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appriciated :)

Comment: Can you try the boilerplate app and see if it works: https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App/blob/gh-pages/manifest.webapp  Also another thing to try is to remove the type privileged just to see if it may be a CSP error you are encountering

Comment: We need more info about the app (strip it down f.e. and post it somewhere). Biggest chance is CSP error. Attach to app manager, debug the app, and then click UPDATE and check the console for any errors.

Comment: Hi, the Boilerplate App works fine thank you. I'll check If I can fix it and if i can I'll answer my question :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the error. It seems to be needed to add

```
  "installs_allowed_from": [
    "*"
  ],
```

to the manifest file. My app does no ask for the permission and displays the location. Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the underlying issue. Can you put your app up somewhere?

Comment: Hi I could but exchaning the manifest file solved the issue - the App was just ~8 Lines of JS code to retrive the Location. I'll look where I'll upload those.